# Why does this test still expect my function to throw an error even if I have already done so?

Tags: javascript, arrays, exception, error-handling, throw

timeseries is an array in the following format:

```
[ {"date": "2012-12-21", "price": 1.234}, ... ]
```

My code:

```
function first(timeseries) {
  if (timeseries.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  var earliestIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < timeseries.length; i++) {
    if (timeseries[i].date === null) {
      throw new Error("no date");
    } else {
      if(Date.parse(timeseries[i].date) < Date.parse(timeseries[earliestIndex].date)) {
        earliestIndex = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return timeseries[earliestIndex].price;
}
```

Test result:

[image: testResult]

The question did not specify the exact value of date when not provided.

Why is this so? I have already thrown an error.

Comment: Please provide the code as text in the post

Comment: Well, what is the value when the date is not provided? Is it exactly `null`…?

Comment: Can you  provide the test data for test case #3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions to cover all cases.

1. Test if timeseries[i].price is null or not before returning.
2. You may want to try using `==` instead of `===` as it will also do the necessary type conversions before check.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/4874271

Tip: COPY the code and format it here instead of posting photos, would be easier for people to answer. :)